# Segmentation Fault in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I am trying to produce a code that appends a value "val" to the end of an array "ia", however I keep getting a segmentation fault. Can anyone help me point out as to where the source of the error might be coming from?

Right below is a test code I made for task 4.

```
intarr_result_t intarr_push( intarr_t* ia, int val )
{


    if (ia ==0)
    {
        return INTARR_BADARRAY;
    }

    //making space for newarr
    ia = realloc(ia, (ia->len + 1) * sizeof(intarr_t));

    //copying data from ia and val to newarr
    ia->data[ia->len - 1] = val;

    //ia = newarr;
    if (ia == 0)
    {
        return INTARR_BADALLOC;
    }
    else
    {
        return INTARR_OK;
    }


}
```

with the following custom header file:

```
/* Structure type that encapsulates our safe int array. */
typedef struct {
  int* data;
  unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;

/* A type for returning status codes */
typedef enum {
  INTARR_OK,
  INTARR_BADARRAY,
  INTARR_BADINDEX,
  INTARR_BADALLOC,
  INTARR_NOTFOUND
} intarr_result_t;

/* TASK 4 */

// Append val to the end of ia (allocating space for it). If
// successful, return INTARR_OK, otherwise return
// INTARR_BADALLOC. If ia is null, return INTARR_BADARRAY.
intarr_result_t intarr_push( intarr_t* ia, int val );

// If the array is not empty, remove the value with the highest index
// from the array, and, if i is non-null, set *i to the removed value,
// then return INTARR_OK. If the array is empty, leave *i unmodified
// and return INTARR_BADINDEX. If ia is null, return INTARR_BADARRAY.
intarr_result_t intarr_pop( intarr_t* ia, int* i );
```

Comment: You never initialized `ia` before assigning to `ia->data`.

Comment: Your assignment to `ia->data` is also wrong. You can't create an array like that, you have to call `malloc()` and then set each element.

Comment: Effectively `ia = realloc(<undefined value>, (<undefined value> + 1) * sizeof(intarr_t));`.

Comment: You need to go back to the books and learn how to use arrays and pointers in C.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I used malloc to ia in a previous task which I think is related to this somehow...and I updated my code so that it looks more close to what I am going to submit to the class' server.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you `realloc` `ia`, while should realloc `ia->data`. `ia` itself is of constant size, which is `sizeof(intarr_t)`. Correct piece of code would read:

```
ia->data = realloc(ia->data, (ia->len + 1) * sizeof(*ia->data));
/* ... */
if (ia->data == 0)
/* ... */
++ia->len;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
/* Structure type that encapsulates our safe int array. */
typedef struct {
  int len;
  int data[];
} intarr_t;

intarr_result_t intarr_push(intarr_t** ia, int val )
{
    intarr_t *tmp = *ia;
    if (tmp ==0)
    {
        return INTARR_BADARRAY;
    }

    tmp = realloc(tmp, sizeof(intarr_t) + sizeof(int) * (tmp->len + 1));
    if (!tmp) return INTARR_BADALLOC;

    /* copying data from ia and val to newarr */
    tmp->data[tmp->len++] = val;
    *ia = tmp;

   return INTARR_OK;
}

int main(void)
{
    intarr_result_t res;
    intarr_t *arr = malloc(sizeof(intarr_t));

    if (!arr) return 1;
    res = intarr_push(&arr, 10);
    /* TODO: Something with result */
    res = intarr_push(&arr, 20);
    /* .... */
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Potentionally changing array object address on each push makes it hard to share such variable between different objects or threads.

Comment: "The realloc function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object could not be allocated." This is what the standard says about realloc, if you want to use this then you must expect a change of address for the program to reliably work.

Comment: What I meant is that if I would have two objects each storing its own pointer to the array, and one of objects decides to push a value, and realloc returns different address, second object would contain invalid pointer which would eventually lead to issues. Reallocating `data` member, on the other hand, would not change the address of the array object itself.

Comment: @mike.dld yep, that sounds like a good idea, Hmm... I don't know why I made it so complicated :-p

Comment: BTW Using temporary variable during reallocation is actually a good idea if one wants to report error and not lose old data :)